# Prettier - Config for HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, prettier

I want to specify string lengths for HTML and JS in one config file .prettierrc.

```
 module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 80,
  [HTML]: {
    printWidth: 150,
  },
};
```

But in log i got:

```
ReferenceError: HTML is not defined
```

Comment: In that line, it expects `HTML` to refer to an existing variable and there is no such variable so that error seems reasonable. Looking at https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides, it looks like overrides should be specified using a "files" option, so something like `"files": "*.html"` should work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using the `.prettierrc` format instead, `visual studio code` will also provide intellisense when you use this format.

You are getting the error because:

- The file needs to be in the JSON format,
- Any overrides need to be specified under the `overrides` JSON key

**In your case the file should look like this:**

`.prettierrc`

```json
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.html"],
      "options": {
        "printWidth": 150
      }
    }
  ]
}
```